# A program to find if the sum of the elements in the middle three rows equals to sum of elements in the middle three columns of matrix print

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program to find if the sum of the elements in the middle three rows equals to sum of elements in the middle three columns of matrix print. So far am able to find the sum of all the columns and rows in the matrix.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{

    static int array[10][10];
    int i, j, m, n,sum = 0;
    printf("Enter the order of the matrix\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    if (m>=5&& n>=5)
    {
        printf("Enter the elements of the matrix\n");
        for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        {
             for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
             {
                  scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
             }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        {
             for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
             {
                 sum = sum + array[i][j] ;
             }
             printf("Sum of the %d row is = %d\n", i, sum);
             sum = 0;
        }
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
            {
                 sum = sum + array[i][j];
            }
            printf("Sum of the %d column is = %d\n", j, sum);
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The matrix should be a 5 by 5 or bigger");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the introductory text on what questions to ask on SO. Here, in particular there is not even a question. And if you have a real question and post code here, format it properly such that we can easily read and reuse it.

Comment: where u r checking middle 3 rows and column?

Comment: are you paid by line count? what's this fetish with empty lines?

Comment: How do i get to compare the sum of the three middle rows with the sum of the three middle columns?

Comment: @Himanshu It is you who should check the middle 3 rows and columns. Otherwise the question would not be asked.:)

Comment: Himanshu, that's where am stack...

Comment: Find the (integer) half of `n`, loop between `n/2-1` and `n/2+1` and do the same in a second loop for `m`.

Comment: @Alex If it works then mark my answer as the best.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int mid1 = (m-3)/2;
int mid2 = (n-3)/2;
int sum1=0,sum2=0;
//suppose m is 9 index(0-8), so this for loop will add the index 3,4,5  
for(i=mid1; i<mid1+3; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        sum1+=array[i][j];  
    }
}
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    for(j=mid2; j<mid2+3; j++)
    {
        sum2+=array[i][j];  
    }
}
if(sum1==sum2)
//equal
else
//not equal
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the array has n rows and m columns. In this case you can calculate the sums of  middle three rows and columns the following way

```
if ( n >= 3 && m >= 3 )
{
   int k = ( n - 3 ) / 2;
   int l = ( m - 3 ) / 2;

   int cols_sum = 0;
   int rows_sum = 0;

   for ( i = k; i < k + 3; i++ )
   {
      for ( j = 0; j < m; j++ ) rows_sum += array[i][j];
   }

   for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
   {
      for ( j = l; j < l + 3; j++ ) cols_sum += array[i][j];
   }

   if ( rows_sum == cols_sum ) /* print appropriate message */;     
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   3
#define M   3
#define RANGE   3

int main( void )
{
    int array[N][M] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };
    size_t n = N;
    size_t m = N;

    if ( n >= RANGE && m >= RANGE )
    {
        size_t k = ( n - RANGE ) / 2;
        size_t l = ( m - RANGE ) / 2;
        size_t i, j;

        int cols_sum = 0;
        int rows_sum = 0;

        for ( i = k; i < k + RANGE; i++ )
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < m; j++ ) rows_sum += array[i][j];
        }

        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( j = l; j < l + RANGE; j++ ) cols_sum += array[i][j];
        }

        if ( rows_sum == cols_sum )
        {
            printf( "The sums of three middle rows and columns are equal "
                    "each other and have value %d\n", rows_sum );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "The sums of three middle rows and columns are not equal "
                    "each other.\n"
                    "The sum of the rows has value %d "
                    "and the sum of the columns has value %d\n", 
                    rows_sum, cols_sum );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
The sums of three middle rows and columns are equal each other and have value 45
```

Now all what you need is to provide the appropriate dimensions of the array and the user input of the data.

Comment: @Himanshu  By the way it was a funny typo because the program was correct even with this typo.:)

Answer (score 0):

In you code you are asking user for `row and column count`, but you have already decided on that, moreover you cannot create a `array` dynamically with user input. However, there are ways you can work with to create arrays based on users request, we have `Dynamic Memory Allocation` concept to the rescue. For for time being, work with predefined size.

**How to get row Data**

In c, you have to fix on a row as `i`, in `array[i][j]` `i` is row and `j` is column reference, and loop through `j` to get all the row element values

**How to get Column Data**

same as above, loop through `i` and fix on `j`, exactly opposite.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
/*This code works for only odd numbers and you have to make necessary changes to accommodate for even number of rows and columns*/
const int row = 5, colmn = 5;
static int array[row][colmn];
int i, j, m, n,sumRow = 0, sumColmn = 0;
int middleRow = row / 2, middleColmn = colmn / 2;
int howManyRows = 3;
printf("Enter the elements of the matrix\n");

/*
* first get elements from user
*/
for (i = 0; i < row; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < colmn; ++j)
    {
        printf("[%d][%d]",i,j);
        scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
    }
}
/*
* printing elements to cross check the output
*/
for (i = 0; i < row; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < colmn; ++j)
    {
        printf("%d\t",array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*
* logic : get rows to adds (outer loop will loop through the rows to consider)
* inner loop is to get all the elements in each row
*/
for(int threeRows =  0 - howManyRows/2 ; threeRows <= howManyRows/2 ;threeRows++)
{    
    for (j = 0; j < row; ++j)
    {
        sumRow += array[j][middleColmn + threeRows];            
    }
}

/*
* its the same as above just the opposite 
*/
for(int threeColmn = 0 - howManyRows/2; threeColmn <= howManyRows/2 ;threeColmn++)
{    
    for (j = 0; j < row ; ++j)
    {
        sumColmn += array[middleColmn + threeColmn][j];            
    }
}

printf("middleRow = %d  middleColmn = %d  sumRow = %d sumColmn = %d",middleRow, middleColmn,sumRow,sumColmn);
if(sumRow == sumColmn) printf("\nThey are equal");
else printf("\nnot equal");
return 0;
}
```